# Regular Expression to Find Number in String - As Word OR Number

Tags: php, regex

I need to be able to match a string in a music album name containing "Volume" to convert it to a standard format, so the following examples would all become **"This is a Test, Vol. 1"**:

- "This is a Test Volume 1"
- "This is a Test Volume. 1"
- "This is a Test Volume.1"
- "This is a Test Vol 1"
- "This is a Test Vol. 1"
- "This is a Test, Vol 1"
- "This is a Test, Volume 1"

I've got it pretty much there after a few minutes of messing, but there's a problem. I ONLY need to match when there is a number after it, but this number may be written as a number (1, 2 ,3), or a word (one, two, three). These numbers could get relatively high, say, 20 (twenty), etc. Obviously if the album was called "Turn up the Volume", I **don't** want it to change this to "Turn up the, Vol. ".

How do I do this?

This is what I've got so far:

`/,*\sVol(ume)*\.*\s*/gi`

https://www.regex101.com/r/tI8nV7/1`

There's also another case which adds more complexity:

- **"This is a Test (Volume 1)"**

This should still get converted to: "This is a Test, Vol. 1"

Comment: did you want to match `Vol.3` ?

Comment: What is biggest number in words? Can it be `Volume Eleventh` also?

Comment: @BT643 I think what you want is a look-ahead. E.g. `/,*\sVol(ume)*\.*\s*(?=(\d|one|two|three))/`

Comment: is your string always end with a number. like This is volume 8 or it contains more characters like this is volume 8 for Rock

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes I want to match Vol.3.

Comment: @anubhava Yes it could go to "Eleven", and possibly even "Twenty" or so.

Comment: @UnicoRahul Yes it *could* contain words after like you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookahead to check for the match would be followed by 123 or string one , two, three.

```
,?\h*Vol(?:ume)?\.?\h*(?=(?:[123]|one|two|three)\b)
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/tI8nV7/2)

Comment: This is almost there! Works great until we get to "Volume 10". How would I include 10 in the [12345678910] group?

Comment: try `(?:10|[1234567890])\b`

Comment: This seems to work better as I don't have to add each number individually:  `(?:\d+|one|two|three)\b`

Comment: yep, but you specified 1,2,3 only.

Comment: Sorry, I've just clarified the question. The numbers could get relatively high (I imagine around 20 or so).

Comment: Ideally, yes, but I realise it could go on forever. I understand that there's probably nothing that's going to do that (although something that could would be amazing!).

This works well enough in my case: `/,?\h*Vol(?:ume)?\.?\h*(?=(?:\d+|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|ninteen|twenty)\b)/i`

If no one suggests a library for finding numbers as words, I'll mark this as the answer :) Thanks!